# Can not use inline function of retrofit

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, retrofit

I'm trying to create an inline function with the response of Retrofit, but when I press the `.` and try to call the function is not visible, I've tried without the call and it's visible.

I have this

```
@GET("url")
suspend fun getModel(): Response<ModelEntity>
```

And my inline function is

```
inline fun <T, R> safeCall(
    block: () -> Response<T>,
    transform: (T) -> R,
    errorFactory: FailureFactory = FailureFactory()
): Either<ErrorEntity, R> =
    try {
        val result = block()
        when (result.isSuccessful) {
            true -> Either.Right(transform(result.body()!!))
            false -> Either.Left(errorFactory.handleCode(result.code()))
        }
    } catch (exception: IOException) {
        Either.Left(errorFactory.handleException(exception))
    }
```

But I'm not able to call something like

```
service.myList().safeCall(...)
```

Even if it's returning a `Response<T>`

My idea is to call it like this

```
override fun getMessages() =
   service.getMessages()
         .safeCall(transform = { it.map { msgs-> msgs.toDomain() }})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your function:

1. An extension to the type you want it to be called on.
2. make transform last parameter to use it outside braces (recommended in clean architecture, not necessary).

You can implement your function in this way:

```kotlin
inline fun <T, R> Response<T>.safeCall(
    errorFactory: FailureFactory = FailureFactory(),
    transform: (T) -> R
): Either<ErrorEntity, R> =
    when (this.isSuccessful) {
        true -> Either.Right(transform(body()!!))
        false -> Either.Left(errorFactory.handleCode(code()))
    }
```

Now since your `safeCall` is an extension of Response, now you can call it on a response like this:

```kotlin
// response is of type Response<T> where T is Any?
response.safeCall(myErrorFactory) { it.map { msgs-> msgs.toDomain() } }
```

---

## Edit:

If you want to catch exceptions, in doing the calls, you can use this approach:

```kotlin
inline fun <T, R> safeCall(
    block: () -> Response<T>,
    errorFactory: FailureFactory = FailureFactory(),
    transform: (T) -> R
): Either<ErrorEntity, R> = ... // your original function body
```

To call this function:

```kotlin
// myErrorFactory optional
safeCall(service::mylist, myErrorFactory) { it.map { msgs-> msgs.toDomain() } }
safeCall(service::getMessages, myErrorFactory) { it.map { msgs-> msgs.toDomain() } }
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid that double bang !! on the body?

Comment: Which is the difference? And how can avoid the !! in the body()??

Comment: @StuartDTO, difference is in the passing the function as reference, or how you call the function. And you can't remove !! since it can return null. A null body only header request is possible in http.

Comment: @StuartDTO you can avoid it however, by specifying a default value like empty string. `result.body() ?: ""`, if result was returned null then it will be replaced by empty string instead of throwing an error